# selenium webserver multi pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I started a scraper multi pages with python and selenium for my company a couple days a go.

It works, but it's very slow... arround 20seconds for each page. I would like to get him faster. My problem from this line call 3 times :
`browser = webdriver.Firefox()` Have You got an idea how can I do it better please?

This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from data_class import *
import time

def get_data_object(link):
    """
    return data object with values saved
    """
    data = Data()
    try:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get(link)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(link + "\033[31m" + " => Failled" + "\033[0m")
        return
    try:
        data.set_title(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.epi-fontLg"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\ttitle missing")
    data.set_extracte_date(time.time())
    data.set_url(link)
    print(data.url)
    try:
        data.set_date_post(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("time"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\tdate missing")
    try:
        data.set_compagny_name(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.bw-release-companyinfo h3 span"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\tcompagny name missing")
    try:
        data.set_ticket_code(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div#cic a span"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\tticket code missing")
    try:
        data.add_hash_tag(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.hash-tags li a.hash-tag"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\thash tag missing")
    try:
        data.add_cash_tag(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.cash-tags li a.cash-tag"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\tcash tag missing")
    try:
        data.set_content(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.bw-release-story"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("\tcontent missing")
    return data

def save_data_object(link):
    """
    save data object and add it in BDD
    """
    data = get_data_object(link)
    ... ADD IN BDD ...

def get_links_pages(link):
    """
    get all links from the pages have to be scrape
    """
    try:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get(link)
        list_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#headlines ul.bwNewsList li a.bwTitleLink")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(link + "\033[31m" + " => Failled" + "\033[0m")
        return
    for list_link in list_links:
        save_data_object(list_link.get_attribute("href"))

save_data_object(url)
```

Comment: Did you try just to move `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` out of functions? Also note that if you want to improve your working code it's better to ask question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did, the problem is than change the variable browser and create exception in the second loop ...